# PowerShell: Upload documents to folder in document library

Tags: powershell, document, file-upload, folder, library

I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2010.

I have to make a PowerShell script that copies a structure found on a network share. Its all good except for one thing... I know how to make Document Library's and folders inside them, I also know how to upload files to the document library's BUT I can't find out how to upload a file to a folder inside a document library.

For clarification:
Document library
 -Folder
 -Folder -->Upload to this folder
 -Folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a Document library:

```
New-SPList -Web http://spwebaddress -ListTitle “Enter Title Here” -ListUrl “ListURL” -Description “Description” -Template “Document Library”
```

To upload to a folder within document library you should get the spfolder then add to it...

```
$folder=$web.GetFolder(“FolderName″)
$folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + “/” + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
```

References:

http://sharepointgroup.wordpress.com/2012/08/17/how-to-upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-document-library-with-powershell/